# Why do I get Attribute error when i typed exactly from page

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I'm practicing and learning as i go, I get a attribute error, exact error is " 'str'object has no attribute 'get_bars', here is the code,
Any help gratefully received

```
    # retrieve daily bar data for SPY in a dataframe 
    spy_bars = rest_api.get_bars('SPY', TimeFrame.Day, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-30').df
    spy_bars.head(3)

    # quote and trade data also available for equities
    #spy_quotes = rest_api.get_quotes('SPY', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-05').df
    # spy_trades = rest_api.get_trades('SPY', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-05').df
```

Comment: How have you imported the library ?

Comment: What is `rest_api`?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I think the OP is working with this library - https://pypi.org/project/alpaca-trade-api/

Comment: And from what page did you type?

Comment: hello Yuri ill put up a new post showing complete code

Comment: I'm sorry simple coding mistake, a date format was incorrect

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example